# Tables relationship: Pre-filled table X newborn table

Tags: mysql, database, select

Have this already created and populated table:

```
CREATE TABLE `form` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varbinary(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employeer` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `occur_type` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3747;
```

I just created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `prefor` ( 
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`r1` VARCHAR( 3 ) NOT NULL ,
`r2` VARCHAR( 160 ) NOT NULL ,
`r3` VARCHAR( 160 ) NOT NULL ,
`r4` VARCHAR( 160 ) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

What can I do to return a result that shows data inserted in current `prefor` `r1`, `r2`, `r3` and `r4` line, plus the entire `form` current line at the same `SELECT`?

Comment: Imagine we know nothing about the relationship between your tables. What you imagine turns out to be the reality.

Comment: The relationship is: The user will fill the two tables. First the `prefor` then the `form`. But he can inform his name or not! The `form`.`id` is currently auto-incremented 3476 times, and the `preform`.`id` is currently `null`. What is the best solution for me to create the link between this two tables?

Comment: The form table can store the prefor id of the prefor table.

Comment: Why have you opted for varbinary for 'name'?? And seriously consider storing dates and times as a single entity, and using an appropriate data type. Finally, note that incrementing column names are nearly always indicative of poor design.

Comment: This is my question. How can I auto-increment the column `prefor_id` stored on `form`, or update the value on it one by one?

Comment: As I said. This table has been created before. I can't answer about these things you asked. All I know is: It is working fine... I just want to assemble another table to the PHP which calls this table.

Comment: See LAST_INSERT_ID.

Comment: Doesn't help. It returns the last PK inserted on whole BD. It doesn't guarantee that the last PK is for my request. This BD generates a log, stored on a table which creates a PK too. SELECT prefor.id + for.id + 3473 works? Can you post your reply like an answer? I can't initiate a chat cuz of my reputation. Thanks

Comment: Yes it does. It's session specific.

Comment: In the same php_session will be inserted 2 auto increments. One for `prefor` and another for `for`. It is inserting the value `0` on BD. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the tip of @Strawberry, I am trying to implement the following `php` code:

```
$idpreform = mysql_insert_id();
$record= mysql_query("INSERT INTO form (name, employeer, occur_type, contact, phone, message, date, time, id_preform) VALUES '$name','$employeer','$occur_type','$contact','$phone','$message','$date','$time', '$idpreform')",$id) or die("Insert error.".mysql_error());
                    echo '<br>Mysql_insert_id: ', mysql_insert_id();
```

Before this, there is a php code that is writing on the same BD but different table. In this case, auto-incrementing a field. In this moment, as I said, the BD is writing the second auto-increment.
On the `echo` above, the code returns the auto-increment field `id` value from the table `form`. On the BD, it is writing `0`. How to fix this?